# Is it possible to “sniff” a .m3u8 url of a video playing on a website in iOS?

Tags: ios, m3u8

I'd need the url of the .m3u8 of the video to pass it to some more efficient app (i.e. vlc or similar) to play it without annoyances… there's an app called Video Grabber that should do the job but it can't deal with advertising multiple redirects

Comment: you could perform a GET request to the URL of the website and check the response for any <video> tags, then just grab the src attribute from that tag

Comment: What data are you needing? The codec of the video? What is the protocol? HLS? RTSP?

Comment: You need to provide more detail here. is this inside an iOS app you are building? You cant extend the Safari browser on iOS except with things like the sharesheet and content blocking. Sharesheet may give you what you need as you can pass off the entire site page to your app to then extract the .m3u8 link

Answer (score 0):

use the chrome extension called .m3u8 sniffer
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-m3u8-sniffer-find-h/akkncdpkjlfanomlnpmmolafofpnpjgn